# Weird issue(s) in cloning Windows 10 between SSDs

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clone, mmc

My PC currently has an M.2 SATA SSD as its system drive with Windows 10 1809 installed. Today I got myself a new M.2 NVMe SSD and want to clone the OS over, so I can spare the SATA one for something else. However, I encountered a series of issues:

1. **[Primary issue]** I tried Macrium Reflect (a frequently recommended tool for cloning), EaseUS ToDo Backup and AOMEI Partition Assistant, they cloned at adequate speeds, and I was able to boot from the resulting NVMe SSD, but when I unplugged the SATA SSD and booted into the OS, it didn't take long for me to discover that **MMC doesn't work at all**. Trying to run any `*.msc` (e.g. Event Viewer, Disk Management) gave an error saying "The external backing provider is not recognized", and trying to summon Device Manager from `This PC - Manage` gave "This file does not have an app associated with it...". Searching doesn't give anything useful, so it looks like even the internet has never seen the issue before.

   I thought some system files might be broken, so I tried these:

   - `sfc /scannow` within the OS halted at ~20%, saying "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation". Doing the same from a Windows installation disk wouldn't even start, with the same error.
   - `chkdsk` found some errors but situation didn't change after correcting them.
   - Trying to do an in-place upgrade with a Windows installation disk, even with the latest ISO (August 2019), always ended up with it rolling back changes towards the end of the process.

   **The weirdest part is**, I accidentally discovered that when I leave the SATA SSD in (i.e. both SSDs are in), even if I boot from the newly cloned NVMe one, MMC still works. It's as if the OS specifically needs something from the SATA SSD, despite its ID and drive letter has changed.
2. Another route I took was Ghost disk-to-disk cloning. For some reason it was painfully slow (<100MB/s, way slower than 1), and after cloning when I unplug the SATA SSD and boot, it threw me into a blue Recovery screen, almost identical to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLhGc.png). I tried to fix it by messing with `diskpart`, and it managed to boot, but then we're back to issue 1 where MMC doesn't work.

Obviously I want to avoid installing Windows from scratch, but what can I do next?

---

Appending some details per request, although I don't see why necessary (since the steps are pretty much just there in the cloning softwares used):

1. Disk info: SATA SSD is ~476GB and has the Windows partition along with EFI, reserved and recovery partitions. NVMe SSD is ~465GB (slightly smaller). Windows partition has plenty of free space, and by default all below cloning methods deal with the size difference by shrinking Windows partition to fit. Additionally, `chkdsk` reported no errors.
2. Ghost 12.0: booted from a PE environment; chose local disk-to-disk operation.
3. Macrium Reflect: selected source drive then "clone this disk"; defaulted to Intelligent Sector Copy; cloning done within Windows.
4. EaseUS ToDo Backup: selected "clone"; selected "Optimize for SSD" in Advanced options; cloning done within Windows.
5. AOMEI Partition Assistant: selected "Migrate OS to SSD", choosing the empty unpartitioned NVMe as target; PC rebooted to a PreOS environment to do the cloning.

Comment: You’re trying to fix problems caused by a clone after the clone. You need to fix the clone process. Please detail, with screenshots, what you are doing to clone your drive. If it was cloned properly, this would not happen. You are either resizing partitions improperly, or you are not cloning the entire drive. Once the drive is cloned you need to remove the original drive then boot windows. In addition, I would recommend running chkdsk on the running, original system before cloning and I would recommend cloning the drive using an offline method with the clone application run from a boot disk.

Comment: Each clone process costs 30min to more than 1hr - I can't go back and resupply screenshots for all of them. I can try to append some details with text, but these are nothing out of the ordinary. The only detail that I think might matter is a small difference in disk size, which I'll also note.

Comment: I’m not asking to detail all of them. Pick an app, then detail what options and steps you are using. Things are going wrong somewhere in the clone process. Don’t forget to consider my other recommendations as well.

Comment: Done. As I said, I see nothing out of the ordinary with these steps... I rarely do disk operations, and therefore rely on simple steps, touching as few options on the way as possible. 2 of the 3 methods are offline. I'll do chkdsk as soon as my PC is idle.

Comment: Update: tried EaseUS, same result.